# how to make a shader like this bottle's in blender 2.81?

Tags: materials, shaders, glass

[image: Bottle]

how to make a shader like this bottle's in blender 2.81 ?

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far and why aren't you satisfied? I guess the basis of a glass shader is a mix between a Glass and a Transparent node

Comment: A glass shader should work. Keep in mind the IOR does have an influence on its behavior. In my opinion though, as an artist, you need to be aware of EVERYTHING in a scene. Contributions to the look and feel you want to achieve. In this case I think you are attracted to the "reflections" in the glass. So, yes, you need a material shader that is transparent AND that reflects. But, you also other need objects in the scene for "it" to reflect. Light sources and other objects. In this scene it looks like a combination of oblong blue light(s) and at least one white light are illuminating.